# What Type of Coaxial is this?

Tags: wiring, coaxial-cable

I've been to at least 3 hardware stores trying to find a fitting that will work for this cable. I've had a hell of time getting an RG-6 compression fitting on here. RG-59 won't fit either. It looks like there's metal wires, then a metal jacket, followed by more metal wires, a second metal jacket, white foam, and then the copper wire. From what I can tell this is a triaxial cable but the fittings for that are over $50. What is this cable and where can I find fittings for it?

[image: coaxial cable]

Comment: What is this cable used for?  Have you looked down along the jacket of the cable to see writing that provides the ID of the cable? Almost all cable has jacket labeling that will ID the cable type.

Comment: the picture does not show the diameter of the cable .... you have ignored the important info that is printed on the cable

Comment: There's nothing printed on the cable, sorry forget to mention.

Comment: It's used for cable internet.

Comment: If you’re have trouble getting an RG6 connector to slide on, the you likely have quad shield or RG6Q.  Look for connectors that advertise for use with quad cable or have a Q designation like this: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B008C7ZCCO/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_JCtoBbVTPA3K8. (Also RG59 is much smaller than RG6 so if you’re having trouble getting an RG6 connector on then it’s most likely quad cable)

Comment: Yep, that was it. Needed a RG6Q.

Comment: Which metallic layers are in physical contact with one another? If they are incontact they are the same layer electrically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Memorializing the answer I suggested in comments, since OP says it’s correct)

If it looks like RG6 and an RG6 connector is hard to slide on, then it’s likely RG6Q or quad shielded RG6 cable.  You’ll need a connector marked for RG6Q, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008C7ZCCO):

[image]

RG6 and RG6Q “look” very similar but the specs are different enough to require RG6Q connectors.  (Also RG59 is much smaller than RG6 so if you’re having trouble getting an RG6 connector on then it’s most likely quad cable.)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably rg58 since rg6 & rg59 won't fit if memory serves it is narrower or thinner than 6& 59. It is 50 ohm where 59 is 75 ohm.